# Passing parameters with call_user_func?

Tags: php

Is there a way to call a function using call_user_func and pass it parameters? For instance I have

```
function test($args)
{
    echo "I DID IT!";
}
```

however I cannot call this function because it has a paramter which is not being passed by

```
call_user_func("test");
```

is there a way to call the function and provide parameters to it? (for instance, the ability to pass in a list arguments)? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It takes you less time to write this question than to google "call_user_func"?

Comment: @FrancisAvila: googlability of a question does not make it invalid. This site is also supposed to be a reference for others.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php), you can supply a list of parameters as array.

Answer (score 42):

If you were to [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) you would see that `call_user_func()` accepts a variable number of arguments:

```
call_user_func('test', 'argument1', 'argument2');
```

You can also use [`call_user_func_array('callback', array('array','of','arguments'))`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

Comment: I tried the second solution, but instead of multiple arguments it's going as single argument

Comment: Did you change the function name from call_user_func to call_user_func_array? Because it should be passed as multiple arguments.